# Android Game Programming by Example книга Джона Нортона - не пойму получение переменной

Tags: java, android

В книге Джона Нортона "Android Game Programming by Example" на 118 стр. автор создаёт переменные класса Viewport

```
Viewport(int x, int y){

 screenXResolution = x;
 screenYResolution = y;
 screenCentreX = screenXResolution / 2;
 screenCentreY = screenYResolution / 2;
 pixelsPerMetreX = screenXResolution / 32;
 pixelsPerMetreY = screenYResolution / 18;
 metresToShowX = 34;
 metresToShowY = 20;
 convertedRect = new Rect();
 currentViewportWorldCentre = new Vector2Point5D();
```

Это цитата

*Now, let's look at the constructor. The constructor just needs to know the resolution
of the screen. This is obtained in parameters x and y, which, of course, we assign to
screenXResolution and screenYResolution, respectively.
Then, as previously suggested, we divide those two previous variables by two and
assign the results to screenCentreX and screenCentreY, respectively.
The pixelsPerMetreX and pixelsPerMetreY are calculated by dividing by 32 and
18 (again, respectively), so a device with a resolution of 840 x 400 pixels will have
pixels per meter x/y of 32/22. Now, we have variables that refer to the number of
pixels of screen real estate on the current device that represents a meter of our game
world. We will see a number of times in our code, where this will be useful.
We will actually draw a slightly wider area than this, to make sure we don't have any
unsightly gaps/lines around the edge of the screen and assign 34 to metresToShowX
and 20 to metresToShowY. Now, we have variables that refer to the amount of our
game world that we will draw each frame.*

К сожалению мой английский не настолько хорош как хотелось бы. Поэтому я не понял, почему разрешение экрана по ширине делится на 32, а по высоте на 18? Откуда эти цифры? Может быть я не смог правильно перевести объяснение? Помогите разобраться

Comment: и все тут же пошли смотреть на 118 страницу книги))) приложите текст, скриншот или хоть что-то, что позволит посмотреть на первоисточник

Comment: @Andrew, исправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это количество ячеек или знакомест которые будут выводиться в окне игры по горизонтали и по вертикали. В данном случае 32*18. Можно поэкспериментировать и установить другие значения соблюдая два условия: числа должны быть четными, а размер ячейки по горизонтали и по вертикали должны стремиться к одному значению для уменьшения искажения.

Величины `metresToShowX = 34; и metresToShowY = 20;` выбраны на 1 больше для каждой стороны, чтобы закрывать возможные "пустоты" из-за округления размеров ячейки. Так что реально будет выводиться сетка размером 34*20.
Автор в книге предупреждает, что игра на разных устройствах с разным разрешением будет смотреться по разному (вытянутой по горизонтали или вертикали). Для учебных целей это приемлемо.
В качестве домашнего задания можно попробовать устранить этот недостаток ;) .

Наверное в книге и правда есть ошибка.

*so a device with a resolution of 840 x 400 pixels will have pixels per meter x/y of 32/22.*

Должно быть *32/18*, да и разрешение телефона чаще всего берется *800 x 480*.